# Not able to select dropdown values using selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, dropdown

I am new to automation and currently exploring selenium Java for my application
Trying to automate a web application with selenium Java.

I have looked online and can only find answers if the dropdown was 'Select'. Please suggest how i can select a value from the dropdown .

HTML code:

```
<span title="" class="k-widget k-dropdown k-header innova-invalid" unselectable="on" role="listbox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" tabindex="0" aria-owns="" aria-disabled="false" aria-busy="false" aria-activedescendant="32406016-a12b-4ce6-a9f7-56f84a0883bd" style="" xpath="1">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" style="">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span>
<span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select"></span>
</span>
<select kendo-dropdownlist="$ctrl.dropdownList" k-data-source="$ctrl.dataSourceOptions.dataSource" k-data-text-field="'Display'" k-data-value-field="$ctrl.valueField" k-value-primitive="$ctrl.valuePrimitive" name="HSRisk" k-options="$ctrl.options" k-ng-model="$ctrl.model" k-rebind="$ctrl.rebindTimestamp" k-ng-disabled="$ctrl.isDisabled" ng-class="{'innova-invalid': $ctrl.hasError}" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;" class="innova-invalid">
<option value="true"></option>
<option value="false"></option>
</select>
</span>
<span unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default" style="">
<span unselectable="on" class="k-input"></span>
<span unselectable="on" class="k-select" aria-label="select">
<span class="k-icon k-i-arrow-60-down"></span>
</span>
</span>
<select kendo-dropdownlist="$ctrl.dropdownList" k-data-source="$ctrl.dataSourceOptions.dataSource" k-data-text-field="'Display'" k-data-value-field="$ctrl.valueField" k-value-primitive="$ctrl.valuePrimitive" name="HSRisk" k-options="$ctrl.options" k-ng-model="$ctrl.model" k-rebind="$ctrl.rebindTimestamp" k-ng-disabled="$ctrl.isDisabled" ng-class="{'innova-invalid': $ctrl.hasError}" data-role="dropdownlist" style="display: none;" class="innova-invalid">
<option value="true">
Yes
</option>
<option value="false">
No
</option>
</select>
</span>
```

Comment: Both of the dropdowns in your HTML are `select` elements -- what exactly are you trying to click here?

Comment: The <select> elements are hidden.

Answer (score 1):

You can't click on options from select drop-downs. You need to handle them differently.

From your code sample I would say that in order to select an option you have to do this:

**CODE SAMPLE**

```
Select yourSelectSection = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("YOUR_ID")));
yourSelectSection.selectByIndex(0); // by using index
yourSelectSection.selectByVisibleText("Yes"); // or by using text
```

**Note**: you have to import *Select* library. If you need to read more about this library you can do it [here](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Select.html).

Answer (score 0):

```
Select yourSelectSection = new Select(driver.findElement(By.Xpath("dropdown-list")));
yourSelectSection.selectByIndex(0); // by using index
yourSelectSection.selectByVisibleText("true");
```

this will work

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.id(“dropdownField”)).sendKeys(“mention text of required value from dropdown”); //send required option in dropdown field
driver.findElement(By.id(“option1”)).click();
```

Or try with the below code:

```
List<WebElement> options = driver.findElements(By.xpath(“”));
for(WebElement option : options) {
if (option.getText().contains(“mention text of required value from dropdown”)) {
option.click();
break;
}
```

Please refer to the [link](https://biswasarpita.medium.com/selecting-dropdown-option-with-selenium-19ef06e1d5fa) for more details- how to select a particular value in a dropdown without using the methods of Select class in Selenium.